# Bijection between derangements and good permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> A *good permutation* is a permutation of the numbers $1$ to $n$, such that $i$ is not followed by $i+1$ at any position in the permutation, for any $i \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\right\}$. Call the number of such permutations $S(n)$.
>
> Also, $D(n)$ is the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$.
>
> I am required to show that $S(n) = D(n) + D(n-1)$.

Note that an algebraic solution is possible, but I need a combinatorial argument i.e. by showing bijections between the two sets.

Comment: Why do you *need* such a thing?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Bijective/Combinatorial Proofs of  identities like these usually give more insights into the problem at hand, compared to an algebraic solution. I, of course, _need_ this for a homework ;)
(Rest assured though, I gave it enough thought posting here :) )

Comment: This question has been re-asked, and an [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451212/showing-that-q-n-d-nd-n-1/514956#514956) is given at the new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This does not in fact work; see the comments.** Then see the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451212/showing-that-q-n-d-nd-n-1).

HINT: Let $\pi=\pi_1\pi_2\dots\pi_n$ be a permutation of $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$. Define a map

$$\hat\pi:[n]\to[n]:\pi_k\mapsto\begin{cases}
\pi_{k+1}-1,&\text{if }k<n\text{ and }\pi_{k+1}\ne 1\\
\pi_1-1,&\text{if }k=n\text{ and }\pi_1\ne 1\\
n,&\text{otherwise}\;;
\end{cases}$$

$\hat\pi$ is a permutation of $[n]$, and in fact the map $\pi\mapsto\hat\pi$ is a bijection on $S_n$, the set of permutations of $[n]$.

Suppose that $\pi$ is good. Then $\hat\pi$ has no fixed point in $[n-1]=\{1,\dots,n-1\}$. Can you fill in the details and finish it from there?

Comment: I may be mistaken, Brian, but I think the rest of it is the harder part.  (Of course, the OP hasn't responded to your hint, either.)

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks :)

Comment: @Anvit: You’re welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure whether my understanding is correct, but it looks like all cyclic permutations of $\pi_1\pi_2\ldots\pi_n$ have the same image under this map.  For example, $132$ and $213$ would both map to $231.$  In other words, the map seems to depend only on the relative, rather than absolute, positions of the elements of $\pi.$  Please let me know if I've gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: @WillOrrick whoops deleted comment, 132 maps to 213 and 213 maps to 321,  a left cyclic shift minus one mod n

Comment: @Evan: I'm probably being dense, but Brian talks about $\hat\pi$ having no "fixed points" so I assumed he was thinking of permutations as functions from $[n]$ to $[n].$  So $\pi$ is the function $1\mapsto\pi_1,$ $2\mapsto\pi_2,\ldots$  By the permutation $132$ I meant $\pi_1=1,$ $\pi_2=3,$ $\pi_3=2.$  So according to Brian's rule, $\pi_1=1\mapsto\pi_2-1=2,$ $\pi_2=3\mapsto\pi_3-2=1,$ and $\pi_3=2\mapsto3$ since $\pi_1=1.$  In other words $1\mapsto2,$ $2\mapsto3,$ and $3\mapsto1,$ which is the permutation $231.$  I see that you are assuming that Brian meant$\ldots$

Comment: $k\mapsto$ (bracketed expression) rather than $\pi_k\mapsto$ (bracketed expression).  But that doesn't work, since $132$ and $213$ are good permutations, while their images under that interpretation are $213$ and $321,$ the second of which has a fixed point in $[n-1].$

Comment: @WillOrrick hmm you are right, something is funny here, your interpretation was probably intended but has double counting, interesting...