# Number of string permutations with substring of at least two characters as original string

Tags: combinatorics

Assume there are no duplicate characters and there is target string "ABCD"

How many permutations are there of this same string such that there exists a substring of at least two characters?

Examples for "ABCD": ABDC, CDAB, DBCA

Is there a general formula to solve this? Using a backtracking algorithm I get the following numbers for a string of size n:

- n = 1 -> 0
- n = 2 -> 1
- n = 3 -> 3
- n = 4 -> 13
- n = 5 -> 67
- n = 6 -> 411

Originally I thought something like (N-1)^2 * (N - 2) for a string of size N because there can exist at most N-1 two consecutive characters that are a substring and they can be placed N-1 ways. Then there are N - 2 ways to place the remaining characters. This is incorrect as there can be more than one substring within same string (e.g. CDAB). Would appreciate any thoughts, thanks!

Comment: "How many permutations are there of this same string such that there exists a substring of at least two characters?" : I tried to think about how you worded the question, and I also tried to understand your intent by examining the example offered.  I failed.  Can you edit your posting + the offered example to clarify what you are trying to ask?

Comment: If you are careful, you could use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to arrive at these numbers for small cases.  This sequence is discussed at [oeis.org](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C13%2C67%2C411&language=english&go=Search).  They provide a formula using [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: When I was checking your numbers, I used Inclusion-Exclusion to count the number of permutations in which no element is followed by its successor and subtracted that from $n!$ to find the number of elements in which at least one element is followed by its successor (so that the permutation would contain a substring of length at least $2$).

Comment: The linked duplicate addresses the complementary problem, that there are no substrings, so you need to subtract that answer from $n!$. For discussions of the connection with your problem and derrangements, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451212/showing-that-q-n-d-nd-n-1/4429157#4429157