# Derangements such that m < n

Tags: combinatorics

> For $n\in\Bbb N$, let $C_n$ denote the number of permutations of the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ in which $k$ is never followed immediately by $k+1$ for each $k=1,2,\ldots,n-1$.
>
> 1. Find $C_n$.
> 2. Show that $C_n=D_n+D_{n-1}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

How can part 2) be done?

Part 1) is simply

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^i\binom{n-1}{i}(n-i)!$$

Comment: [Bijection between derangements and good permutations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276207/bijection-between-derangements-and-good-permutations) asks about a combinatorial proof of this fact.

Comment: [Showing that $Q_n=D_n+D_{n-1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451212/showing-that-q-n-d-nd-n-1/514956#514956) is the same question asking for combinatorial proofs and actually has answers.

Comment: Note that neither of those questions is an exact duplicate because they ask for combinatorial proofs, while an algebraic manipulation is good in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that

$$D_n=n!\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\;.$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
C_n&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{n-1}i(n-i)!\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i\frac{(n-1)!}{i!}(n-i)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i\frac{n!}{i!}-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^i\frac{(n-1)!}{(i-1)!}\\
&=n!\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}-(n-1)!\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^i}{(i-1)!}\\
&=D_n-(-1)^n+(n-1)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\\
&=D_n-(-1)^n+D_{n-1}-(-1)^{n-1}\\
&=D_n+D_{n-1}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Hi how to get from 4th step to 5th step to become Dn - (-1)^n

Comment: Ok nvm wow i got it. Beautiful :D

Comment: @RStyle: Just to be sure: the $(-1)^n$ is the missing $i=n$ term in $n!\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$. Yes, this is one case in which an algebraic argument seems to be *much* easier than a combinatorial one!

Comment: Yea thanks understood!